# app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined

Tags: angularjs

this is my app.js 
this gives the error **app.js:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined**

```
angular.module('contactsApp',[])
        .run(function ($rootScope) {
          $rootScope.message = "Hello Angular!";
        });
```

this is my main.html
were i load the app.js file

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html ng-app="contactsApp">
        <head>
            <titel>Contacts</titel>
            <base href="/">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="src/bootstrap.min.css"/>
         </head>
        <body>
    <div class="container">
    <div class="page-header">
      <h1>Contacts: {{message}} </h1>
    </div>
    </div>
          </script>
          <script  src="lib/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
           <script   src="lib/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
           <scrip src="lib/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js">         </scrip>
          <script src="src/app.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>

this is my server.js






 var express = require('express'),
        app = express();

    app 
        .use(express.static('./public'))
        .get('*',function (req,res) {
            res.sendfile('public/main.html');
            })
     .listen(3000);
```

And my file structure is
    [this is my directory structure]
plzzz kindly help me!
Im getting error in browser console as 
    [myError](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mCgP8.png)

[file directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pv4Eq.png)

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo when loading angular:
`"<scrip"` instead of `"<script"` (in you `main.html` file)

Comment: Best to close this question as a typo then.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
use(express.static('../public'))
```

OR

```
use(express.static('lib'))
```

your `server.js` in within public folder

Answer (score 0):

Check the path for angular.js. Does it exist in "lib/bower_components/angular/angular.min.js
Alternate way is to use `<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.5/angular.min.js"></script>`